# Why is the inner-box moving when I click a link?

Tags: html, css

I'd like 3 boxes with a background image that floats behind the boxes and overflows the box content.

This code works great when it first loads but when I click on an anchor the selected box moves up. 
I don't understand why the box moves up as its position is set to relative and the parent box doesn't move.

Why does the inner-box move up when I click one of the anchors?

```css
.box>img {
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(0, 80, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#a">Anchor 1</a> <a href="#b">Anchor 2</a> <a href="#c">Anchor 3</a>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a name="a">Anchor  1</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a name="b">Anchor 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a name="c">Anchor 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <a id="a">Anchor  1</a>

Comment: @Sfili_81 it seems to be working even with `name`

Comment: My bad, i don't give an explanation to my comment. In the documentation , to use internal link you must create a bookmark with the id attribute. I'm not sure but seems name is obsolte in html5 [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: `name` Not supported in HTML5. Use the global `id attribute` instead.
  [source]: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky but the behavior is logical and it's due to scrolling. Basically inside your box you are having overflow that you are hiding but we can also enable scroll in order to see the content inside

Here is the code if we consider scroll:

```css
.box>img {
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  margin:10px;
}

.inner-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(0, 80, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  position:relative;
}

:target {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#a">Anchor 1</a> <a href="#b">Anchor 2</a> <a href="#c">Anchor 3</a>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a id="a">Anchor  1</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a id="b">Anchor 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a id="c">Anchor 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now it's clear that we can scroll the content inside the box and it's also trivial that the click on the anchor will also trigger the same scroll in order to move the target to the top of its container. You can easily adjust the scroll and click again on the anchor to the see this *logical* behavior.

Now if you hide the overflow, you will have the same behavior except that you will no more have the scroll bar to manually scroll. In other words, even if you hide the overflow, you can still trigger the scroll like you are doing in your example.

Here is another example to better illustrate:

```css
.box>img {
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  height:40px;
}

.inner-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(0, 80, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

:target {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#a">Anchor 1</a> <a href="#b">Anchor 2</a> <a href="#c">Anchor 3</a>
<div class="box">
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a id="a">Anchor  1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-box" style="background:yellow;">
    <a id="b">Anchor 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a id="c">Anchor 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can clearly see how the content is moving (scrolling) when you click on each anchor.

---

You can find a full explanation of this behavior within the specification: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#scroll-to-fragid

In this *complex* explanation you will find:

> 3. Scroll target into view, with behavior set to "auto", block set to "start", and inline set to "nearest".

Then to understand the *Scroll target into view* refer to this: https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#scroll-an-element-into-view

---

To avoid this behavior in your code, make sure the target is already at the top:

```css
.box>img {
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

.inner-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(0, 80, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 0 20px 20px; /* Remove top padding */
  position: relative;
}
/* Make the anchor behave at the top */
.inner-box a:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:20px; /*replace top padding*/
}

:target {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#a">Anchor 1</a> <a href="#b">Anchor 2</a> <a href="#c">Anchor 3</a>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a id="a">Anchor  1</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a id="b">Anchor 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
  <div class="inner-box">
    <a id="c">Anchor 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent thankyou. I can't see an obvious way with CSS to prevent it scrolling. I could use the image as a background but that doesn't fit what I'm doing. Now I see that its scrolling I can add some javascript to return the block to the top. for example with jquery:     <script>
        $(".box").scroll(function () {
            $(this).scrollTop(0);
        });
    </script>

Answer (score -1):

```
Basically whenever you are adding <img> tag it's width and height should be set 100%.when you hover on img tag you can see it is exceeding that box width and height in inspect element.so just add 
.box>img{
  width:100%;
 height:100%;
position :absolute;
}




    .box>img {
      position: absolute;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }

    .box {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .inner-box {
      border: 1px solid red;
      background-color: rgba(0, 80, 0, 0.8);
      padding: 20px;
      position: relative;
    }
    <a href="#a">Anchor 1</a> <a href="#b">Anchor 2</a> <a href="#c">Anchor 3</a>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
      <div class="inner-box">
        <a name="a">Anchor  1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
      <div class="inner-box">
        <a name="b">Anchor 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x500" />
      <div class="inner-box">
        <a name="c">Anchor 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'd like the image to retain its aspect ratio and float behind the inner box. I'd like the inner box to dynamically size (as it does when the page first loads and before you click on an anchor. Clicking the anchor seems to move the inner box and I don't understand why.

Comment: whenever we give width and height 100% it retains the aspect ratio.

Comment: In your example the image is resizing to the width of the box and the aspect ratio is not retained even with width and height of 100%.